# Sonatype Nexus - Service not starting on launch - MAC

Tags: macos, service, nexus, launchd, sonatype

Okay so following the instructions here

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-service.html

I take the example plist file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.sonatype.nexus</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/nexus/bin/nexus</string>
        <string>console</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and stick it in my /Library/LaunchDeamons folder (I have also tries /System/Library/LaunchDeamons to no avail).

I have set the permissions on the file as specified in the documentation and I can even load the file manually using :

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sonatype.nexus.plist
```

However this does not start the service.

I can start the Nexus instance manually using this command from the terminal.

```
/usr/local/nexus/bin/nexus console
```

**However** on reboot of the device this service is not being launched and I still have to go back into the Terminal and manually call the command to start the Nexus instance.

Can anyone point me in a direction that might fix this? (Brand new to LaunchDeamons)

The console output is shown [image]

Thanks
Aiden

Comment: Hm.. I wrote and tested  the instructions on Lion. It looks like a permissions issue to me ..

Comment: It does seem like that, however I am completely stuck with what permissions are needed to set as I have i think made all the appropriate permissions. I'v given up for the moment in favour of something which i might get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permissions issue. The two options you have are to run Nexus as root user. This is not advisable for servers but might be okay for your local development purposes.

If thats the case you have to set the RUN_AS_USER in the nexus startup script to root and have Nexus installed in a folder root has access to (any really therefore) .. I suggest to use /opt

Better would be to create a specific user e.g. named 'nexus' and set the RUN_AS_USER to that name and make sure the user has full access to the Nexus installation (nexus folder and sonatype work folder).